# getting 404 in GWT RPC with phonegap

Tags: gwt, phonegap

I tried to follow the answers regarding this question but none working for me .

I have a simple helloworld app in GWT which i am trying to run in phonegap on my real android phone.

So i compile my GWT application and put the contents of war folder under www folder (removed anything previously there in www folder) of my phonegap blank project.

I run the project on my Mobile via phonegap .

the address i see in phonegap is :  http://192.168.15.118:3000/

where this app is running .

So i did this in my code.

```
PhonegapUtil.prepareService((ServiceDefTarget) service, "http://192.168.15.118:3000/hellogap/", "greet");
```

service.greetServer( ....

"hellogap"is my module name   (my project name is HelloGap, if its required)

when i run rpc from eclipse all is OK.
when i run rpc on my Mobile, it says :

```
                  Server replies:
             404 Not Found Cannot POST /hellogap/greet
```

If i can get a hint what i am doing wrong ..

thanks

Comment: Running in dev mode, or production mode? Please be aware of the "bindaddress" parameter in the dev mode (which by default does not allow clients from hosts other than localhost to connect).
The error message says 404 and not connection timeout, so this is unlikely to be the cause, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

To access the war like web-browser in android app using Phonegap you must know following things,

1) After compiling deploy your war to the server like Apache Tomcat etc. I am using Apache Tomcat and deploying my war in webapps folder.

2) Your IP must be public IP so that from anywhere you can access that war else make sure that your war and your mobiles internet are in same network.

3) For accessing war from phonegap project in MainActivity you can implement by following way, there are many ways to access war but I prefer this,

```
        @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        /*
         * This is one way to access war
         * super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         * super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/CustomAppHost.html");
         */
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");//here you can specify your war url

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);//here you can specify your war url
                return false;
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

By this approach all Servlets that your using in your project will work, I think this should help you..

Answer (score 0):

Divide et impera!

Phone side: make a call to a service you know for sure it is working, like the yahoo weather api ( https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20wind%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22chicago%2C%20il%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys ).

Server (your computer) side: try to call the api url with a browser and/or with the same GWT app running locally.

Let's see how it goes, and we'll go from there. The question has a wide array of possible issues, we need to narrow it down a bit.